# How can i concatenate two audio files in raw directory using FFmpeg in android?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I search a lot that how can I concatenate two audio files that exist in raw files using FFmpeg library in android can I do that or not? something like the code below.

```
String s = "-i " + R.raw.raw_one + " -i " + R.raw.raw_tow+ " -filter_complex [0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out] -map [out] " + output;
ffMpeg.excute(s);
```

Comment: In ffmpeg "raw" audio generally refers to a bare headerless PCM file, which ffmpeg can concatenate, but I suspect this is not what you mean by "raw".

Comment: you can't do this whit raw folders in android studio just files in storage